# how does javascript onload work within an instance?

Tags: javascript

here is a simple version of what im trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Example(position) {
        this.position = position;
        instance = this;

        img = new Image();
        img.src = 'http://www.gazette-ariegeoise.fr/IMG/jpg/test.jpg';

        console.log(this.position);
        //logs as expected 1 than 2 on the second


        img.onload = function() {
            console.log(instance.position); 
            //logs 2 twice
        }
    }

    ex1 = new Example(1);
    ex2 = new Example(2);
</script>
```

somehow the onload function logs position of the instance 2 twice,

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instance` is a global, so the second call to `Example()` overwrites the first one.

Use `var` to create a local variable.

Better yet, also [use `"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so it won't let you create accidental globals.

Comment: I think he should use `this.instance` instead of instance.

Comment: @PDKnight — In an event handler? That won't work. `this` will be the image, not the `Example` instance.

Comment: It will if he will bind onload function to current instance (new Example).

Comment: @PDKnight — Eh? He's already using `new Example`… but to bind the `onload` function to it he would need to append `.bind(this)` to the function expression.

Comment: Of cours he would, but I think it wouldn't be any problem and I think it's better than to use var and `"use strict"` expression.

Comment: `"use strict"` is just good practise and everyone writing JS should do it all the time. Rebinding `this` is only a good idea if you don't want to use `this` to access the image object as well. Using a closure to store a reference to the newly created `Example` object is idiomatic JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin is it btw okay to store 'this' inside a local variable or is there a beter way to acces it inside a anonymous function?

Comment: @herriekrekel — It's fine. As I said in my previous comment, it's idiomatic.

Comment: Well...what's the difference between using variable and "use strict" expression and using this.somevar expression?

Comment: @PDKnight — Using a variable stores it in a variable. Using `"use strict"` makes creating a global variable by accident an error instead of a gotcha. Using `this.somevar` gives you a different object for each of the two functions so you don't get the value you tried to store.

Comment: Thanks for explanation :)